# How to map the result set with specific columns of a JPQL query with dynamic projections to an entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am querying a database using jpql and my query is getting generated dynamically, i.e, both projections and predicates. However, I am not able to map the result set to get proper JSON response.

Entitlement Entity

```
@Entity
public class Entitlement{
    @Id
    @GenetedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "license_id")
    private String licenseId;
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private String customerId;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="product_uuid")
    private Product product;

    //setter getters and constructors
}
```

Product Entity

```
    @Entity
    public class Product{
    @Id
    @GenetedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="product_uuid")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "isbn")
    private String isbn;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String name;

    //setter getters and constructors
}
```

EntitlementDaoImpl.java

```
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select e.customerId,e.licenseId,p from Entitlement 
                  e,Product p where e.product_uuid = p.product_uuid");
    List<Entitlement> list = query.getResultList();
    return list;
```

JSON response Received:

```
    [
        "customer101",
        "license123",
        "product": {
            "id":201
            "isbn":"abvhgfdWDMNB"
            "name":"sample_book"
         }
    ]
```

Expected JSON:

```
    [
        "customerId":"customer101",
        "licenseId":"license123",
        "product": {
            "id":201
            "isbn":"abvhgfdWDMNB"
            "name":"sample_book"
         }
    ]
```

Comment: You have to create a DTO that holds that data

Comment: I tried..but the result is still the same

Comment: do you wants to select the list of Entitlements by given Product id ????

Comment: And how does your DTO look like? and how did you use it?

Comment: I want to list both entitlement and product, i.e, product wrapped in  respective entitlement where productId for both table is same

Comment: DTO is exactly similar to the Entitlement entity mentioned above and used it as:

List<EntitlementDTO> list = query.getResultList();